# Joomla Migrating Live Site To Localhost - Menu Items Not Working

Tags: php, sql, joomla, xampp, localhost

so just migrated a Joomla site from live to localhost. Have the front end up and can access the backend no problem.

Front end wise none of the menu items work.

I have renamed the live site variable to point to http://localhost/domain
Also disabled SSL via config and disabled .htaccess files.

Permissions have been added for tmp and cache directories where required. Wondering what else I could be missing. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Wondering if this could be db or file related, relevant details below

```
public $live_site = 'localhost/Clients/domain';
public $log_path = 'F:\\ClientDevEnvs\\htdocs\\Clients\\domain\\logs';
public $tmp_path = 'F:\\ClientDevEnvs\\htdocs\\Clients\\domain\\tmp';
```

Have also edited httpd.conf file to enable and enabled htaccess mod rewrite. bamboozled

Comment: You may like to speak to the audience @ https://joomla.stackexchange.com/ if you don't receive sufficient support here.

Comment: Why are you using a $live_site?  try just leaving it empty.

Comment: Hi guys, already posted with joomla stack exchange and removing live site variable doesn't unfortunately solve the problem. I did disable SEF Urls also.